# Alineamiento de objetos en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Quiero hacer una pantalla en Flutter pero no se muy bien como acomodar los objetos, aún no logro comprender rows/columns. Tengo un texto en el centro y más abajo dos Icons pero esos Icons no están alineados en una columna.Cualquier sugerencia me sería de gran ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Alerta'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors:[ const Color(0xFFfcaeae),const Color(0xFFfcf3e6)] )
        ),
        child:  Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('DANGER', style:TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0,color: Colors.red[300],fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            InkWell(
                child:  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child:  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.call),
                        iconSize:90.0,
                        onPressed:(){print('Telefono Clickeado');} ,
                      ),
                    )
                )),
            InkWell(
                child:  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.location_on),
                        iconSize:90.0,
                        onPressed:(){Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> DeliveryScreen()),);},
                      ),
                    )
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
```

Comment: seria bueno que agregues una imagen en tu pregunta para entender como quieres acomodar tu layout

Comment: Ya añadí una imagen Diego. Lo que preciso es dejar el texto en el centro y más abajo, alineados en una lista a cierta distancia los íconos. Pero soy nuevo en Flutter y no lo he podido realizar.

Comment: no entendí bien como quieres que quede

Comment: Lo que dice Danger en el centro y los dos iconos abajo de ese texto. Los iconos deben estar alineados. En la imagen un icono está más arriba que el otro. Lo que busco es que estén uno al par del otro. Con una cierta distancia de separación. Me disculpo si no me explico con claridad.

Comment: entiendo, dame unos minutos para corregirlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un cambio sencillo para que puedas conseguir la alineación que deseas es meter tus botones en un `Row`, el `Row` es un contenedor de elementos en horizontal, a diferencia del `Column` que es vertical.

```
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                      child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                            child: new IconButton(
                              icon: new Icon(Icons.call),
                              iconSize: 90.0,
                              onPressed: () {
                                print('Telefono Clickeado');
                              },
                            ),
                          ))),
                  InkWell(
                      child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                            child: new IconButton(
                              icon: new Icon(Icons.location_on),
                              iconSize: 90.0,
                              onPressed: () {
                                /*Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => DeliveryScreen()),
                            );*/
                              },
                            ),
                          ))),
                ],
              ),
```

Te recomiendo que revises los widgets de layout de este link: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout

Comment: Entendido Diego, revisaré el link. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Se valora mucho.